# revert SafeERC20: low-level call failed

Tags: solidity, truffle, erc-20, aave

SIO2 is aave v2 foked version on Astar chain. I want to execute flash loan on it and have the following code:

```
function myFlashLoanCall() public returns (bool){
        address receiverAddress = address(this);

        address[] memory assets = new address[](2);
        assets[0] = address(0x7f27352D5F83Db87a5A3E00f4B07Cc2138D8ee52);
        assets[1] = address(0x3795C36e7D12A8c252A20C5a7B455f7c57b60283);

        uint256[] memory amounts = new uint256[](2);
        amounts[0] = 0 ether;
        amounts[1] = 0.0001 ether;

        // 0 = no debt, 1 = stable, 2 = variable
        uint256[] memory modes = new uint256[](2);
        modes[0] = 0;
        modes[1] = 0;

        address onBehalfOf = address(this);
        bytes memory params = "";
        uint16 referralCode = 0;

        LENDING_POOL.flashLoan(
            receiverAddress,
            assets,
            amounts,
            modes,
            onBehalfOf,
            params,
            referralCode
        );
        return true;
    }
```

Whenever I try to call the `myFlashloan()` I am always getting this error in truffle: `revert SafeERC20: low-level call failed`. Even I have used the debugging feature of Truffle but not able to solve the issue. May someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Here's my test case to call `myFlashloan()`:

```
it("Calling myFlashLoanCall()",async ()=>{
        let reponse = await debug(myFlashLoanV2.myFlashLoanCall());
    })
```

*Note: Truffle is not able to stop at `debug()` call even testing with `test --debug` in truffle console.*

Answer (score 0):

Since the loan is on behalf of the your smart contract it also should implement the `IFlashLoanReceiver` interface [from the Aave docs](https://docs.aave.com/developers/v/2.0/guides/flash-loans/iflashloanreceiver).

My best guesstimation here is that the `LENDING_POOL` is trying to send the flasloan to your smart contract but since it is not implementing the `IFlashLoanReceiver` the call is failing.

You have to provide more details to your question because the error is happening in the `LENDING_POOL.flashLoan(...)` which execution is depending not only on the `myFlashLoanCall()` function but on the whole smart contract implementation.